# Create log file using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create a log file by using a `.htaccess` script.
I have a image directory in which I want to place the `.htaccess` file which will write all file names which is accessed from this image folder.

I now need to create a log inside image folder.

I tried with `RewriteLog` but it's not working for me.
I am using Apache version 2.4.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with just `htaccess` alone. You will need some form of server-sided language to handle this (something like php).

Answer (score 4):

After going through Apache documentation for log creation, I found that Apache not allowed to write code for log creation in .htaccess file.
We need to write code in httpd.conf file.

[Source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

My code to write log file for all images in httpd.conf file is:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.JPEG|\.JPG|\.PNG|\.GIF|\.JFIF|\.TIFF|\.BMP)$" image-request=log
CustomLog logs/unwanted-requests.log common env=image-request
```